# How to Push Spark DataFrame parallely to ElasticSearch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi Currently I am able to Push Data to Elastic search but in sequential manner.
Step 1. Connect with Target DB
Step 2. Fetch Records in Chunks to Spark Data Frame 
Step 3. Push it to ES.

Is there any way i can fetch all records only one time and push spark Dataframe to ES in parallel way.

Comment: One solution would be .foreachPartition and execute a udf with batchIterator and use elastic4s package to write to elasticsearch

Comment: **Got solution - we used pyspark using Python.**

1. Created Spark Dataframes with some configurations like
numPartitions, partitionByColumn, Lower Bound and Upper Bound.
.option("numPartitions", <Number>) 

2. Push those Dataframes to ES.

3. Run it with Spark submit on cluster to get good performance